# Showing certain elements in tensor product is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Let $l/k$ be a finite field ext. of $k$,
and $b_1, ..., b_d$ be a $k$ basis of $l$.
How can I show that $1 \otimes b_1, ..., 1 \otimes b_d \in A \otimes_k l$ is linearly independent over $A$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any $k$-linear function $\epsilon:A\to k$ such that $\epsilon(1)=1$.

Now suppose there is a linear combination of your elements with coefficients in $k$ which is zero, and apply to it the linear map $\epsilon\otimes\mathrm{id}_l:A\otimes_kl\to k\otimes_kl=l$.

Comment: Is it obvious that such a map always exist? Thanks!

Comment: It is just linear algebra. Show that: if V is a k-vector space and v a nonzero element of V, there exists a linear function $V\to K$ which takes v to 1.

Comment: Wasn't the OP asking for $A$-linear independence? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez , I have same question as Pgatti, why this implies it's $A$ linear independent? both of the answer only shows $k$-linear independent?

Answer (score 0):

The map $L\longrightarrow A\otimes_K L$ in an injective ring homomorphism : hence if $\sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i (1\otimes b_i)=\sum_{i=1}^d \lambda_i (1\otimes b_i)=1\otimes\sum_{i=1}^d ( \lambda_i b_i)=0$, then $\,\sum_{i=1}^d ( \lambda_i b_i)=0$, hence $\,\lambda_i=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,d$.

Comment: Notice that the claim the OP wants to prove is pretty much *equivalent* to «the map $x\in L\mapsto 1\otimes x\in A\otimes L$ is injective».

Comment: But the latter is triviial since the source of  the ring homomorphism is a field…

Comment: Well, the map could be zero. There *is* something to be proved.

Comment: It's supposed to map $1$ onto $1$.

Comment: No, the map sends $1$ to $1\otimes1$, and you have to check that $1\otimes1$ is not zero in $A\otimes L$.

Comment: I supposed it was proved it's a ring homomorphism – it's a basic fact? Anyway $k \rightarrow A$ is injective, and $L$ is free over $k$, hence flat.

Comment: Going through flatness is further complicating the issue!

Comment: I know  it's probably not the way the O.P. can see things, but it's a fact that freeness of L over $k$ implies injectivity.